# 2D tiling with regular pentagons (and generalizations)

Tags: reference-request, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, polygons, tiling

We know that the only regular polygons that can tile the 2D plane are triangles, squares, and hexagons. One way of seeing this is that, if we try to place regular pentagons (for instance) around a point, we are forced to have overlaps (see picture):

[image: Three pentagons at a corner showing a narrow triangular gap; four pentagons at a corner with two overlapping.]

However, if we ignored this and kept wrapping around, after placing 10 pentagons in a "spiral shape" around this corner, we would eventually return to our starting pentagon. If we "unflattened" the tiling, we would see a surface like this, with pentagonal chunks:

[image: Three-sheeted surface with single-sheet projection.]

In 3D this surface would have to pass through itself, but in 4D we could do it without self-intersections. What is known/studied about the geometry of the resulting 2D surface, or Riemann surfaces that would be equivalent to this? What if we changed it to regular septagons, or regular polygons of any number of sides?

Comment: Isn't it the Riemann surface associated with $z^{1/5}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It should only have 3 sheets about any one vertex, because after 10 pentagons I line up with my starting point, and it should have infinitely many vertices - one for each point of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_5]$, where $\zeta_5 = \exp(\tau i/5)$ is a primitive 5th root of unity. Wouldn't $z^{1/5}$ have five sheets about the origin?

Comment: You are right...

Comment: $z^{1/3}$, then?